# Mapping text to Mel Spectrogram and conversion of text to input feature representation in Tacotron 2

Tags: audio, deep-learning, nlp, audio-processing, spectrogram

I'm trying to understand how text is converted to Mel spectrograms.

I'm having difficulty understanding how the **text** is mapped to the **Mel spectrogram** according to the figure attached and also what each of the blocks inside (character embedding, 3 conv layers and bi-directional LSTM) from another figure is doing to convert text into input feature representation according to the paper **Tacotron-2**.

I have looked upon several online articles but haven't found an explanation. So please help in explaining how it works.

[Text mapping to Mel Spectrogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfvCY.jpg),
[Part of Architecture from Tacotron-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3KBS.jpg)